# Could I write $H_0^1(\Omega) = \mathcal{D}(\Omega) \cap H^1(\Omega)$?

Tags: inner-products, weak-derivatives

Let space $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ of compactly-supported smooth functions on a domain $\Omega$. I have a few difficulties to understand what is the $H_0^1(\Omega)$. Am I right if I write $$H_0^1(\Omega) = \mathcal{D}(\Omega) \cap H^1(\Omega)?$$

Comment: Why should $H_0^1$ functions be smooth?

Comment: I think you are right to ask this question. Clearly, $u \in H^1_0$ is not necessarily doesn't need to be smooth. @user251257 Could you explain in clear words what is $H^1_0 (\Omega)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't write that. The following definition is more intuitive and correct:

$$ H_0^1(\Omega) = \{u \in H^1(\Omega) \mid \forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists \varphi \in \mathcal D(\Omega) : \Vert u - \varphi \Vert_{H^1} \leq \epsilon\}$$

That means essentially that $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ is dense in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and since you construct $H_0^1(\Omega)$ as the closure of $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ respecting the $H^1$-norm.
It actually holds that $\mathcal D(\Omega) \cap H^1(\Omega) \subseteq H_0^1(\Omega)$ as we take the closure of $\mathcal D(\Omega)$. I hope that helps you :)

Comment: Could you tell me, with your definition, why a Dirichlet eigenfunction $u$ is in $H_0^1$? For example, we know that for $\Omega=[0,a]$, the eigenfunctions are on the form $\varphi_k (x) = \sin(\frac{k \pi}{a} x)$.

Comment: You can use mollifier functions in $\mathcal D(\Omega)$.